# MySQL vs SQLSERVER syntax for selecting into a declared variable

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssms

i need to verify that the customer has not already been entered, in mysql i can do this by selecting the customer id into a variable (@V_CustomerID) below.  However, ssms doesnt like the syntax, is there another way i can accomplish this?

```
Create procedure AddCustomer(
    @CustomerFirstName as varchar(50),
    @CustomerLastName as varchar(50),
    @SiteName as varchar(50),
    @CustomerPhone1 as varchar(20),
    @CustomerPhone2 as varchar(20),
    @CustomerAddress1 as varchar(20),
    @CustomerAddress2 as varchar(20),
    @CustomerCity as varchar(50),
    @CustomerState as varchar(5),
    @CustomerZip as char(5)
    )
    as
    begin

        declare @V_CustomerID as int,--use this to store the returned value
                @V_CustomerExists as bit --use this to store the result of the if else condition

        --First we should check if the customer data already exists in the table--
            select dbo.customer.CustomerID 
                into @V_CustomerID
            from 
                dbo.Customer
            where 
                dbo.customer.FirstName = @CustomerFirstName and dbo.customer.LastName = @CustomerLastName and dbo.customer.sitename = @SiteName;

        if @V_CustomerID is null

        begin
                --Yay!  we can insert the customer--
                        insert into Customer
                        values(@CustomerFirstName,@CustomerLastName,@SiteName);
        end
        else
        begin
                set @V_CustomerExists = 1 
                print 'Customer already exists';

        end

    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer @ http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/variables/

SET @your_variable = (
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) 
    FROM 
        yourtable.yourcolumn 
);